# Spotfire Cross Table Visualization Format

Tags: javascript, crosstab, spotfire

Is there a way to do this in spotfire cross table? The column header of the current format would be my data in vertical axis while the horizontal axis would be the date format. I'm not be able to find any sample from the net that the format is look like from my sample below.

Example format would be like:

[image: Sample Cross Table]

BR,

JV

Answer (score 1):

The first part of this question is easy to get:

[image]

[image]

The second part with the YTD you can get with a grand total column. You just cant rename the Grand Total column heading:

[image]

The third part with the Projected is where you will have problems. If you try to add it in this form it will show the projected heading/value repeated across all the month dates. You really need a higher level visualization. I would just create two pivot tables and place them really close to each other. I don't think there is a clean way to get this higher level data to show without having the heading repeat for each date, unless you have projection data by month and don't mind summing it up like a grand total again. Going off what you show, I would do something like this:

[image]

And set up markings so that when you click, the related rows are highlighted/other rows fade out:

[image]

Finally, you could make one chart a details chart of the other by setting up markings. This makes it look a little cleaner and gives it some added interactivity:

[image]
[image]

Obviously all formatting/names etc. are up to you. This is just made up sample data. Two charts isn't ideal but because you have two different grains I am not sure there is a way to cleanly smash them into the same visualization.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark. My concern is the code column which are came from cell values.
Here are the sum case statement that generate the values.  Is this applicable on the first part question?     
      Sum(case  when ([Type]="Main") and ([input]=1) t 
      Then 1 else 0 end) as [input]
      Sum(case  when ([Type]="Main") and ([pass]=1) 
      then 1 else 0 end) as [pass],  
      Sum(case  when ([Type]="Main") and ([fail]=1) 
      then 1 else 0 end) as [fail], Thank you.

Comment: Hi Mark. Please ignore my reply. I followed your instruction and i got what i'm looking for in my dashboard and its already working. I will try work on the last part. Thanks a lot. cheers..

Comment: Hi Mark. it's possible to put a background color per family like the whole section of A_model the background color would be light gray, B_model is light blue or put a background color for all the input per family and the associated rows?  Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, Spotfire doesn't support row-based coloring on a condition in a Cross Table. If you're creating an analysis with multiple visualizations, you could potentially use a details visualization to limit the rows displayed in the table to a selected well. I added a screenshot of what this would look like. If you used a regular table you could color by condition, but that would not look as nice as a Cross Table.